# Has there ever been a piano in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

Basically what the title says.  I'm fairly certain pianos aren't canon in the *Star Wars* universe, but has there ever been an instance (in the EU, Disney canon, or non-canon works like *LEGO Star Wars*) where a piano has existed?

Comment: there might have been one in the casino in Episode 9

Comment: what do you mean by piano? Max Rebo is certainly playing a keyboard instrument - https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Red_ball_jett_organ

Comment: What about Weird Al's Anakin Guy (no link at the moment)?

Comment: @CaptainJamesT.Kirk - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEcjgJSqSRU I briefly considered including it, but it's a parody (e.g. produced without authorisation from LucasFilm) rather than a non-canon but licensed property like Lego Star Wars

Comment: @Valorum You don't think Weird Al got permission from LucasFilm?  I know he makes a point of getting permission from the musicians he parodies (even though he doesn't legally have to), I'd imagine he might do the same with film studios?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - There's a big difference between getting clearance and getting a licence

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We see someone playing what looks very much like a double-keyboard piano at the Canto Bight Casino in *The Last Jedi*

[image]

And there's an upright piano being played in the Lego Star Wars special [Bombad Bounty](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_Bombad_Bounty)

[image]

Comment: I'm going to argue that that is *NOT* an upright piano in Bombard Bounty, but instead an electric organ.  This is based on the music being played in that scene having reggae roots.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Jefferson Starship from the Star Wars Holiday Special.

Comment: That's not a piano

Comment: @Valorum Well a very predictable comment.  It's clearly a space piano that likely follows the same key scale as an Earth piano.  And it has black and white keys like an earth piano.

Comment: Is the holiday special really canon?

Comment: @AJFaraday: [Which level of canonicity does the Star Wars Holiday Special hold, relative to other works?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23291/which-level-of-canonicity-does-the-star-wars-holiday-special-hold-relative-to-o)

Comment: Most of the discussion about whether or not this classifies as a piano has been removed; lets just leave it be now. I don't think we really need to have such a debate on the matter and even if it's bending the rules of the question (in your (the reader's) opinion) that's not necessary a bad thing for something like this.